# seleccionar solo una fila en material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, table, material

Hola estoy usando https://material-table.com/ para mostrar información en una tabla.
En esta tabla necesito poder usar la propiedad de selección para poder escoger filas de la tabla.

La restricción es que solo se debe poder escoger una sola fila.

Además de que puede que la tabla ya tenga preseleccionado alguna fila. en dado caso el comportamiento sería que se debe deseleccionar dicha fila para que se habiliten todas las demás y si se selecciona otra se vuelvan a deshabilitar todas las demás. Pero no logro conseguirlo.

Estoy usando React.

```
<MaterialTable
        title="Clientes"
        columns={whTableColumns}
        data={sapBusinessPartnerCatalog}
        isLoading={isFetchingCatalog}
        options={{
          ...whTableoptions,
          showSelectAllCheckbox: false,
          selectionProps: handleSelectionProps
        }}
        onSelectionChange={handleOnSelectionChange}
      />
```

para preseleccionar hago algo así

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isBusinessPartnersSelectionDialogOpen) {
        if (currentSelectedClients.length > 0) {
            currentSelectedClients.forEach(selectedClient => {
                const client = find(sapBusinessPartnerCatalog, client => client.cardCode === selectedClient.cardCode);
                client.tableData.checked = true;
            });
        } else {
            setBusinessPartnerCatalog(whDefaultCatalog);
        }
    } else {
        setBusinessPartnerCatalog(whDefaultCatalog);
    }
}, [isBusinessPartnersSelectionDialogOpen]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del atributo options de MaterialTable agrega un propiedad extra llamada selection.

Quedaria algo asi:

```
<MaterialTable
        title="Clientes"
        columns={whTableColumns}
        data={sapBusinessPartnerCatalog}
        isLoading={isFetchingCatalog}
        options={{
          ...whTableoptions,
          showSelectAllCheckbox: false,
          selectionProps: handleSelectionProps,
          selection: true
        }}
        onSelectionChange={handleOnSelectionChange}
      />
```

[Fuente](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection)